# How to change a LINQ list into an arraylist

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sqlite

I have to write a query in a web application using LINQ but I need to change that query into an array list. How can I change the query below to do this?

```
var resultsQuery =
    from result in o["SearchResponse"]["Web"]["Results"].Children()
    select new
    {
        Url = result.Value<string>("Url").ToString(),
        Title = result.Value<string>("Title").ToString(),
        Content = result.Value<string>("Description").ToString()
    };
```

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`.  What are you doing with the result?

Comment: Do you mean `ArrayList` or `List<T>`? Former, from days before generics, would be an unusual choice of collection with little advantage over an `Array` for the results of a LINQ expression.

Comment: hi thank you giving response actually i have gettting data into list that list values store into arraylist.....

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to create an ArrayList, you can write `new ArrayList(resultsQuery.ToArray())`.

However, you should use a `List<T>` instead, by writing `resultsQuery.ToList()`.

Note that, in both cases, the list will contain objects of anonymous type.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i have try arraylist like   ArrayList resultsQuery=o["SearchResponse"]["Web"]["Results"].Children(); but showing error

Comment: `new ArrayList(resultsQuery.ToArray())` (or `(from ... select ...).ToArray()`)

Comment: var o = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(page); this is my list values from this i can get values ....into array what i posted in above code....

Answer (score 1):

There is a .ToArray() method that'll convert IEnumerable to an Array.

Comment: Sorry there is no toarray intelligece not showing toarry it showing only tostring..

Comment: You need to wrap the whole query with () and then try .ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

[`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83h9yskw.aspx) doesn't have a constructor or Add(Range) method that takes an `IEnumerable`. So that leaves two choices:

- Use an intermediate collection that does implement `ICollection`: as both `Array` and `List<T>` implement `ICollection` can be used via the `ToArray()` or `ToList()` extension methods from LINQ.
- Create an instance of `ArrayList` and then add each element of the result:

  ```
  var query = /* LINQ Expression */
  var res = new ArrayList();
  foreach (var item in query) {
    res.Add(item);
  }
  ```

The former method is simple to do but does mean creating the intermediate data structure (which of the two options has a higher overhead is an interesting question and partly depends on the query so there is no general answer). The latter is more code and does involve growing the `ArrayList` incrementally (so more memory for the GC, as would be the case for an intermediate `Array` or `List<T>`).

If you just need this in one place you can just do the code inline, if you need to do it in multiple places create your own extension method over `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static class MyExtensions {
  public static ArrayList ToArrayList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> input) {
    var col = input as ICollection;
    if (col != null) {
      return new ArrayList(col);
    }

    var res = new ArrayList();
    foreach (var item in input) {
      res.Add(item);
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```